# Count number of left nodes of a tree in mysql

Tags: mysql

Following is my table structure

**id name parent **

```
1 King  0     

2 Scott 1    

3 Tiger 1    

4 Oracle 2  

5 MSSql  2  

6 MySQL  3
```

I wish to count the number of child nodes under King

In MSSQL i was able to do it using WITH for recursion. How to do the same using MYSQL

Comment: question is not clear,,, what is the mean of---I wish to count the number of nodes at left of King?

Comment: How do you define which node is left, right, center or whatever? Is `Scott` left node of `King` or/and is `Tiger` the left node?

Comment: I've added lrflag field for identification

Comment: That's not really answering the question. I could now ask the same for `Oracle`and `MySQL` being left nodes of `Scott`. I suppose you want child nodes to be ordered by their `id`. So the smallest child id is the left node, right? Furthermore I suppose this is always a binary tree, right?